# SQL: get the latest record in each day of each user

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table that looks like

```
user_id behavior time
A B1 2020-05-30 09:07:21
A B1 2020-05-31 12:38:21
A B2 2020-05-31 14:39:23
B B1 2020-05-31 12:32:09
```

I would like to get the latest records in each day of each user, so the above table will become

```
    user_id behavior time
    A B1 2020-05-30 09:07:21
    A B2 2020-05-31 14:39:23
    B B1 2020-05-31 12:32:09
```

I look to some other questions in stackoverflow but did not find exactly what I am looking for.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I am using snowflake, so they stated that they used ANSI SQL.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with `row_number()`, you have to partition by `user_id`, `behavior` and `date`.

```
select
    user_id,
    behavior,
    time
from
(
    select
        *,
        row_number() over (partition by user_id, behavior, to_date(time) order by time desc) as rnk
    from yourTable
) val
where rnk = 1
```

Output:

```
| user_id | behavior | time                     |
| ------- | -------- | ------------------------ |
| A       | B1       | 2020-05-30 09:07:21      |
| A       | B2       | 2020-05-31 14:39:23      |
| B       | B1       | 2020-05-31 12:32:09      |
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear, but you can use `qualify` either way.  If you want the last time per `user_id`/`behavior`, then:

```
select t.*
from t
qualify row_number() over (partition by user_id, behavior order by time desc) = 1;
```

If you want the last rows on the most recent day for each user, then:

```
select t.*
from t
qualify dense_rank() over (partition by user_id order by date(time) desc) = 1;
```

`qualify` does filtering like `where` and `having`.  However, it allows the use of window functions.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query, you can use simple min() function,

```
select user_id, behaviour, min(time) group by user_id, behaviour;
```